# Postgres ERROR: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vagrant

I have setup a VM with Vagrant, using a box that mirrors [Heroku-Cedar](https://vagrantcloud.com/acronym/heroku-cedar) and am trying to run our Rails application locally.

When trying to run `rake db:create` or any rake db command, I always get the following error:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

If I try to include the default vagrant username and password into database.yml, I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "vagrant"
```

I'm new to Vagrant and Postgres, so any help to get the database up and running so I can run the application is greatly appreciated

Comment: do you have set any password in the installation time ??

Comment: or goto `pg_hba.conf` and change all `MD5` to `Trust`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set the vagrant user password in postgres and that solved the problem.